# Datatables in Firestore

Tags: datatables, google-cloud-firestore

I created web app which takes data from Firestore to Datatables.

What is the best option to save 2d array from Datatables in Firestore.
Firestore doesn't accept 2d arrays so I thought about 2 options

Invoicing as example

1.Arrays (rows) as fields

```
DOC
-field: invoiceNumber
-field: Customer
-field: position1(row array)
-field: position2..
-field: position3..
...
```

2. Products from one invoice in separate documents (row per document-all invoice docs in the same collection: "invoices")

   DOC(row1)
       -invoiceNumber: 234
       -productSKU: ABC-1
       -productPrice: 23
       -productQTY: 20

   DOC(row2)
   -invoiceNumber: 234
   -productSKU: ABC-2
   -productPrice: 15
   -productQTY: 10

Maybe another better option?

Comment: I think that the second option you described should work a little bit better as you would be making better use of the Documents in Firestore.

Comment: I created field with array and each array element is string (one row in Datatables as string comma separated) :
0 "1,BS-WHITE,100,100"
1 "2,BS-WHITE-3,100,100" but I still testing

Comment: Sure thing, if you need further help, update this and I'll try and help you out as much as I can